# Android singleton over several services

Tags: java, android

I have a problem with my singleton class that is used by services. The singleton is called by 2 services to make a notification. The singleton counts 2 variables for the 2 services.

The problem is:

One counter is only incremented by first services and the second variable by other services though it's a singleton which holds the 2 variables. I don't understand why the two services have different instances of the singleton.

```
public static synchronized NotificationSingleton getInstance() {

    if (mInstance == null) {
      mInstance = new NotificationSingleton();
    } 
    return mInstance;
}
```

This should return the one and only instance of the singleton.

Comment: How do you access your singleton?

Comment: Just with getInstance(). I made a print to show if a new instance is created but there is only one created.

Comment: Are your services running in the same process (that is: does your manifest define `android:process` for your services)? Does your singleton have any non-static nested classes that you're instantiating elsewhere in your code? Also, how did you discover/confirm that there is more than one instance of your singleton?

Comment: That did it! The services weren't running in the same process. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @soMasu: Glad to hear that solved it! I'd suggest to write that up in an answer. You can then accept it (and earn some reputation points) and others running in the same issue may find it helpful too. Win-win. :)

Answer (score 0):

Your singleton implementation is not thread safe. This could be the problem. You should try with [initialization on-demand holder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initialization-on-demand_holder_idiom):

```
public class NotificationSingleton {

    private static final class Holder {
        private static final NotificationSingleton INSTANCE = new NotificationSingleton();
    }

    public static NotificationSingleton getInstance() {
        return Holder.INSTANCE;
    }

    private NotificationSingleton() {}

}
```

Comment: Please support your claim why the original snippet isn't thread safe. Sure, it's not the most efficient (as it could benefit from double-checked locking), but iirc, the lazy initialisation approach is only prone to subtle bugs on pre-Java 1.5. These days that shouldn't be an issue anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Well i will write an answer to the problem myself:

The solution is to add the same android:process="name" to all services in the manifest. They all must run in the same process.